# Function execution time is weird

Tags: c++, function, callstack

I am trying to evaluate the time difference between looping in a linked list with an operation on each element in these two scenarios:

1) Doing the operation inside a function

2) Doing the operation without a function call in the same place

I was expecting that the variation with the function call with be a lot costlier due to the OS overhead of creating and destroying a stackframe for every call, but the results I got was just the opposite. I could not understand why. Could someone please explain what happened?

This is my program:

```
// ConsoleApplication4.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.


#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 

class linked_list_node
{
    int a;

public :
    std::string var;
    bool eval()
    {
        if (var == "abc")
            return true;

        return false;
    }
    linked_list_node() { a = rand() % 100; if (a % 2 == 0) var = "abc"; }
    linked_list_node* nxt;
    std::string getVar() { return var; }

    linked_list_node* getNext()
    {
        return nxt;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    linked_list_node *head = new linked_list_node();
    linked_list_node *trav = head;
    int  len = 75000;

    while (len != 0)
    {
        linked_list_node *n = new linked_list_node();
        trav->nxt = n;
        trav = n;
        len--;
    }
    trav->nxt = NULL;

    //traversal with function
    int length = 0;

    trav = head;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin =          std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while (trav != NULL)
    {
        length++;

        if (trav->eval())
            std::cout << "";
        trav = trav->nxt;


    }
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end =     std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Time difference with function == " <<         std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - begin).count() <<     std::endl;

    //traversal without function
    trav = head;
    length = 0;

    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    while (trav != NULL)
    {
        length++;
        if (trav->var =="abc")
            std::cout << "";
        trav = trav->nxt;

    }
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Time difference without function = " <<     std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - begin).count() << std::endl;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

These are my results :

Time difference with function == 18100

Time difference without function = 33700000

Answer (score 3):

First difference:

In the function, you are comparing the value of `var` to`"abc"`.
In the non-function call code, you are comparing the value of `var` to `"ram"`.

The second difference, the most important one:

In the first case, you are using `std::chrono::microseconds`.
In the second case, you are using `std::chrono::nanoseconds`

After I fix those errors, I get consistently lower value for the second number than the first one.

Comment: @R Sahu, sorry for that, I corrected it.. I checked and I get varied results, sometimes equal, sometimes the functional less, sometimes functional is more, no consistent results, my aim is to see the difference.. but thanks for your answer!

Comment: @s_s, in that case, you are probably running into clock sampling issues. Increase `len` by 100 or 1000 times to remove that as an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're measuring time in different units: `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - begin)` vs `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin)`.

Comment: Glad to help! sorry for the late answer